# How do I connect a 1/2”BSP (F) Swivel inlet with a Quick Connect hose end?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, hose, irrigation

I want to connect [this](https://www.pumpsandpressure.co.uk/pa-rb35-wash-gun---brass-30620000-892-p.asp) washing gun to a hose end (1/2") with a quick connect system. What connector do I need? Any links would be welcome!

For instance, would any of [these](https://www.access-irrigation.co.uk/product-category/hand-watering/brass-snap-connectors/) work?

Comment: On this side of the pond hose bibs are 3/4 npt threads but have an oring or washer seal , the threads do not actually seal the washer or o ring does that the threads pull it tight. I would expect the same in your neck of the woods and would expect any hose fitting designed for quick disconnect to work. A plumbing store could probably give you the fitting in about 10 seconds to make sure you don’t buy the wrong part on line.

Comment: @EdBeal Sure, the problem is that shops are all closed due to Coronavirus situation. That's why I would really appreciate a link or the name of the part at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out your sizes the gun takes a 1/2” BSPM thread 
Your link the male adapter 2.70 pound (your dollar? ) is the right one but there are 2 sizes FQCBM2 is a 1/2 BSP fitting so this should be the correct size.
I hope this gets you all set up it looks like it should from both descriptions.